# Не работает MPMoviePlayerController(), чем заменить для воспроизведения аудио потока на swift?

Tags: swift3, аудио

После 9 версии iOS не работает `MPMoviePlayerController()`. Нашел пример для написания интернет-радио, но он старый и использует этот неработающий `MPMoviePlayerController()`. Чем можно заменить?

Comment: а почему не работает ?

Answer (score 0):

Так попробуй

Глобальные переменные

```
var player : AVPlayer? = nil
var playerLayer : AVPlayerLayer? = nil
var asset : AVAsset? = nil
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem? = nil
```

А это во viewDidLoad:

```
let videoURLWithPath = "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"
        let videoURL = NSURL(string: videoURLWithPath)

            asset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(videoURL) as? AVAsset
            playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

            player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem)

            playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
            playerLayer!.frame = videoView.frame
            videoView.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer)

            player!.play()
```